# How do I get this button layout?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to get this layout.

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/kCjW9"><a href="//imgur.com/kCjW9"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Here's the code I have. I can't seem to get z-index to work so that I could bring black border on top of the background.

```html
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/6a7Ev"><a href="//imgur.com/6a7Ev"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

```css
.btn {
    border-radius: 0px!important;
    font-family: $font-roboto!important;
    font-size: 1.125rem!important;
    text-shadow: none!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
    &.fountain-blue {
        background-color: $color-fountain-blue;
        color: #fff;
        margin-left:5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: -10px;  
    }
}
.btn-border {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 9999!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-border mt-4">
                    <a href="" class="btn fountain-blue">learn more about us</a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this but simple method is to use `pseudo-elements`.  check out the snippet.

**[CODEPEN (SASS version)](https://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/VWyoXL)**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
.btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  text-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 25px);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn.fountain-blue {
  background-color: #65becf;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-border {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.btn-border:after {
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-border mt-4">
  <a href="" class="btn fountain-blue">READ MORE</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it something like this, but than with your own colors and sizes.

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn:before {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<a class="btn">Read more</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 2em;
}

.btn {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  border: .2em solid white;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 7em;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 9em;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  left: -1em;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btn:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: thin solid black;
  height: 2em;
  width: 6.5em;
  top: -.5em;
  left: -.5em;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click me</button>
```